# On the Gibbs Phase Rule, and the structure of nonlinear equations

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

As far as I can tell, the Gibbs Phase Rule gives as a "law" the number of parameters which can be independently/a priori fixed when in an equilibrium with $r$ components and $M$ phases as
$$f = r - M +2.$$
My question is about what it means when $f$ is negative, and why Callen (who I am reading right now) seems to rule out the equilibrium corresponding to $f$ negative.

As a concrete example and for simplicity, take the equilibrium in one component of four phases. The Gibbs Phase Rule says $f = 1 - 4 + 2 = -1$, and so one conventionally concludes that such an equilibrium is impossible. But let us recall the derivation of the phase rule. Strictly speaking, if four phases are in equilibrium then we must have the following three equations (where the subscripts denote phases):
$$\mu_1(T,P) = \mu_2(T,P)$$
$$\mu_1(T,P) = \mu_3(T,P)$$
$$\mu_1(T,P) = \mu_4(T,P).$$
The crux of the Gibbs Phase Rule is to note that we have two unknowns in three equations, and thus that the system cannot be satisfied. My question is *why is this so*? I understand that in general this system may not be satisfied, but why can't things conspire (i.e. the structure of certain, particular $\mu_i$ in a given system) be such that the system is satisfied? Perhaps this has something to do with the nature of nonlinear equations?

Comment: There is a triple *point* for a single component system, meaning $f=0$ but that just means that there is no free parameter left. Similarly, $f=-1$ would just mean a quadruple *point* again without a free parameter. The only way I can  imagine that could happen is having two "normal" triple points infinitesimally close to each other forming a quadruple point in some degenerate case.

Comment: But there is nothing in principle stopping e.g. the triple point from being a line, is there? If there were fortuitously a path in $P,T$ spaceand the structure of the $\mu_i$ were such as to allow it? Of course, this does not happen in practice, but I am talking in principle?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by stopping "the triple point from being a line". If $f=0$ it is a point, it is only a line if $f=1$, but one can have two triple points connected by a line, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_diagram#/media/File:Phase_diagram_of_water.svg, and those triple points are at finite distance apart. I can *imagine* that in some degenerate case, special barely stable symmetry, whatever, the connecting $f=1$ finite line degenerates to an infinitesimal line and then its end triple points coalesce to a quad but I cannot give you an example. Good question, though

Comment: EE18 you maybe interested in this related [exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/773195/could-someone-explain-this-phase-diagram-to-me/773207?noredirect=1#comment1764509_773207) with GiorgioP.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you have the wrong equations. For example, for three phases (liquid, vapor, solid) you have

\begin{align}
T^s &= T^l                                =T^v \equiv T^{eq}                          , \label{eq:thermal_equilibrium_multi}   \\
 p^s (T^{eq},\rho^s)&= p^l (T^{eq},\rho^l) =p^v  (T^{eq},\rho^v)   \equiv p^{eq}    , \label{eq:mechanical_equilibrum_multi} \\
\mu^s(T^{eq},\rho^s)&= \mu^l(T^{eq},\rho^l) =\mu^v(T^{eq},\rho^v) \equiv \mu^{eq} . \\
\label{eq:chemical_equilibrium_1}
\end{align}

which has exactly $N$ equations for $N$ unknowns. This would not change if you consider more or less phases

Comment: the question is about the possibility of having a single component "quadruple" point where four phases come together $f=1-\mathbf 4+2 = -1$, not about a triple point $f=1-\mathbf 3+2=0$.

Comment: @hyportnex This does not change anything. The main part of the question "The crux of the Gibbs Phase Rule is to note that we have two unknowns in three equations, and thus that the system cannot be satisfied" is simply wrong. You may easily extend the equations to four phases.

Comment: Of course a given number can satisfy an untold number of equations, that is without physical significance. The real question is what does $f=-1$ mean and can one have four phases of a single component simple system coalesce at a single point? Can you answer *that* question?

Comment: To quote the great John Tukey: "Far better an approximate answer to the right question, which is often vague, than an exact answer to the wrong question, which can always be made precise. "

Comment: @hyportnex My intention was not to answer the question. There was simply not enough space to write down the correct equations in the comments. I hope the questionier will talk for himself. Good luck anyway.

Comment: As far as I can tell my equations are quite correct, and I’ll add that @hyportnex has captured that which I am unsure of. My question, restated, is why does $f=-1$ necessarily imply we cannot have the corresponding number of phases? Why can’t things conspire such that the overdetermined system does have a solution?

Comment: @EE18 I doubt that. For example considering the standard case of two phases, the temperature is fully coupled to pressure. A dependance of $\mu$ as a function of pressure **and** temperature is formally incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

> The crux of the Gibbs Phase Rule is to note that we have two unknowns in three equations, and thus that the system cannot be satisfied. My question is *why is this so*?

To solve for $n$ unknowns we need $n$ independent equations. If we are given $n+1$ equations and $n$ unknowns, then either (i) there is no solution, or (ii) if there is a solution these equations are not independent.

Case (i) means there is no extra phase.

Case (ii) means that what appears as an extra phase is some combination of the other three phases, i.e., not a new phase.

In either case we cannot have more equations than unknowns, hence the number of degrees of freedom cannot be negative.

Comment: I don think you are *proving* anything beyond restating EE18's problem, and when I say *proving* I mean in a mathematical sense. In all derivations of the Gibbs phase rule I have seen so far it has been tacitly assumed, so it seems to me, that there is always an infinitesimal (nonzero) "piece" along which one can set up a system of equations, say $dp/dT$. If there is no such "piece" then there is nothing that has been proven, and when $f\le0$ then that is the case. Maybe or maybe not can we have four phases come together at one point but the usual proofs do not seem to cover that situation.

Comment: What about the eutectic points where four regions come together? Why can't we consider the solid/liquid mixtures a separate phase?

Comment: @hyportnex Point me to a phase diagram so I can understand what you mean.

Comment: [see, eg.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eutectic_system), four regions (1) $\alpha + \beta$, (2)$L+\alpha$, (3)$L+\beta $, (4) $L$ all come together at the eutectic point. Why can't we call the region, say, $L+\alpha $ region a "phase"?

Comment: @hyportnex There are only three phases in this example (solid $\alpha$, solid $\beta$ and liquid $L$, all on the straight tie line) and the degrees of freedom is $f=1$ (number of components is 2, number of phases is 3). With two components we can have up to four phases, so this does not contradict the phase rule. $L+\alpha$ is like saying "liquid water plus ice," it is *not* a new phase.

Comment: sure, liquid water and ice water is not a separate phase, and is neither an eutectic but what if you have very very small solid alloy pieces mixed in a liquid phase together, a la ferrofluid,  and forming an *eutectic* would you still not consider it as a separate phase?

Comment: Very small pieces of solid alloy in liquid is the same as tiny little pieces of ice in water, or tiny water droplets in air. Mist is not a new phase, it is a mixture of phases. And if mist totally evaporates, then we have one phase, a gas that contains water molecules. Anyway, this is the standard textbook treatment of phase equilibrium.

Comment: Why is (ii) true? Can’t we have $n+1$ different equations which coincidentally conspire to still have a solution in $n$ variables?