# Could someone explain this phase diagram to me?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, phase-diagram, diamond

[image]

I'm a litte confused by this diagram.
What does the "Diamond + metastasble Graphite" and "Graphite + metastable Diamond" regions mean? I mean at room temperature and Pressures, carbon is in the Graphite region, and yet diamonds don't normally turn into Graphite. So what's the difference between the Graphite region and the "Graphite + metastable Diamond" region?

Comment: This is especially interesting considering that here is a single component $C$ and an apparent triple point L+G+D. But is it really a triple point for 3 phases $f=0$, or is it quadruple for four phases $f=-1$, or quintuple for five phases $f=-2$; see the related question of @EE18 and the answer by Themis https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/772329/

Comment: maybe @Themis can answer this

Comment: That means that the kinetics of the phase transition are very slow so one does not experimentally see only pure phase fields. Remember that diamonds don’t spontaneously convert to graphite at STP.

Comment: [It is explained here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_Arkansas_Little_Rock/Chem_1403%3A_General_Chemistry_2/Text/18%3A_Entropy_and_Free_Energy/18.01%3A_Spontaneity_and_Energy_Transfer).

Comment: Standard Gibbs free energy of graphite at STP is 0, while that of diamond is around 2.9kJ/mol. So thermodynamically diamonds are less stable than graphite, but the rate of conversion is so slow as to be negligible due to the high activation energy

Answer (score 4):

I would say that it is a qualitative "effective" phase diagram showing not only the thermodynamic stable phases but the possible presence and coexistence of metastable phases with strong kinetic stabilization (thus stable over macroscopic times).

I call it qualitative because a one-component system cannot have a coexistence of more than three stable phases (according to Gibb's phase rule, which is a consequence of the general coexistence conditions). The presence of a point where apparently five phases coexist means that the graphic resolution around that point is poor, and more careful scrutiny should show the presence of separate but close triple points.

Comment: "because a one-component system cannot have a coexistence of more than three stable phases (according to Gibbs's phase rule, which is a consequence of the general coexistence conditions)." Is there a *mathematical* proof based on first principles according to which not even discrete *points* of dimension $0$ can have more than 3 *stable* phases come together?

Comment: @hyportnex A discrete point of 0-dimension is precisely what is allowed by the phase rule for the coexistence of three phases. More than three phases for a one-component system would result in an overdetermined system.

Comment: Exactly. But an overdetermined system of continuous functions can have discrete point solutions. My question is what excludes *that* possibility?

Comment: @hyportnex, from the mathematical point of view, nothing. But physical equations should be stable against small perturbations. The solution of an overdetermined system can hardly be stable. Stability would require a  very specific functional dependence.

Comment: If I understand you well then it is not that it cannot happen and it is excluded by the usual proofs of Gibbs's phase rule but rather it *can* happen but it will be unstable or requires "a very specific functional dependence". If so, then can this instability be over geological times, as in graphite v. diamond, or if stable what is the required "very specific functional dependence" to make it stable?

Comment: @hyportnex I would rather say that it is such an unlikely event that it can be safely ignored in every reasonable discussion about this issue. However, I'll think a little more about this possibility.

Comment: I have looked into this issue a bit and there is a rather large literature written behind it starting with Gibbs who on page 97 writes "Hence, if r=n+2, no variation in the phases (remaining coexistent) is possible. It does not seem probable that r can ever exceed n+2. An example of n= 1 and r=3 is seen in the coexistent solid, liquid, and gaseous forms of any substance of invariable composition. It seems not improbable that in the case of sulphur and some other simple substances there is more than one triad of coexistent phases. etc.,

Comment: ... but it is entirely improbable that there are four coexistent phases of any simple substance." Note Gibbs' very careful wording - *entirely improbable*! But more modern takes are several and the proofs offered are, sadly, well beyond my mathematical skills. An example, is Chapter 7 Chih-Sing Man: "Genericity and Gibbs's Conjecture on the Maximum Number of Coexistent Phases" in Serrin: Foundations of Thermodynamics and references therein. It would be very educational if somebody could summarize the *actual* results of all that stuff by Man, Coleman, Noll, Fosdick, Feinberg; ....

Comment: ... I tried to understand it but failed. Anyhow, the people in the know call this subject the *Gibbs conjecture*.

Comment: this is the  C-S Man chapter with the references  https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-70803-9_9, if you need it I can post the pages in imgur.

Comment: @hyportnex I cannot access that chapter. If you could post it in imgur it would be great.

Comment: @hyportnex Thanks. It needs a careful study. My first impression is that it is an interesting exercise in Math with limited interest in Physics. Anyway, I'll try to reread it more carefully.

Comment: there is also a newer and equally heavy E. ZANCHINI and A. BARLETTA: A Rigorous Treatment of the Phase Rule., IL NUOVO CIMENTO Vol. 17D, N. 5 Maggio 1995. Can you get it or should I post it?

Comment: @hyportnex I can access it. This paper looks more interesting than Man's one. In the first reading, the authors stress a difference between Gibbs' and Fermi's formulation of how the phase rule is obtained in favor of Fermi's formulation. I think that Gibbs' statement is clarified, although it remains valid: it is highly improbable that there are more coexistent phases than the phase rule says. Of course, the most interesting thing would be a *physical* counterexample. But it cannot be the picture in the question. Thanks for the stimulating inputs.

Comment: I do not want to bother you much more with this just wish to make one more comment. My interest in this subject started with the observation that the Gibbs-Duhem equation does not necessarily hold in its usual form in the presence of *external* fields and/or for  energy form that is not 1st order homogeneous in its variables, such static electric field with charges , but of course all so-called "proofs" of the phase rule assumes Gibbs-Duhem and $U$ being 1st order homogeneous as all the papers, Man, Zanchini, Feinberg,. etc., whose proofs I do not understand, assume. So is it then really true?

Comment: @hyportnex You don't bother me. Unfortunately, the PSE format is not intended for extended discussion, as sometimes Physics would require. My understanding of the phase rule follows Fermi's and Callen's approach, where the emphasis is on the equality of chemical potentials (mentioned in the introduction of Zanchini's paper, which does not require explicitly the homogeneity of the fundamental equation, although the case of external fields introduces additional issues.